# qt quick for android google maps

Tags: android, c++, qt, google-maps, qtquick2

I'm working an application for Android with Qt 5.4,and i'm using Qt Quick, i wanna display a map (google maps or any map), it works fine on desktop but on Android it shows black image (using OpenStreetMaps ).

the module Qt Location is not supported for Android as i've discovered, but also the WebView, so it is impossible to show  map, or is there any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use Google Static Maps API, you can make the request and directly use the result as an image:

```
Image {
    source: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400"
}
```

Naturally, you should compose your own request string dynamically to implement basic interactivity.

If static maps are not enough, you pretty much have to wait for future versions to catch up on supported features.

Comment: Thank you ddriver, i really want the user to choose the location himself, so i should wait for future versions.

Comment: @kharraz - YOU CAN choose the location, take a look at the static maps api page. You can specify it via geographic coordinates.